# update non-available values of one pandas column based on another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2-column dataframe with records:column names ['user_id', 'cookie_id'] and I would like to update user_id values if they are NaN and there is a available user_id value for the common cookie_id.

Example:

```
(before)
user_id   cookie_id
2         15
2         15
3         22
NaN       15
NaN       15
NaN       38

(after)
user_id   cookie_id
2         15
2         15
3         22
2         15
2         15
NaN       38
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need replace only missing values first non missing value per `user_id` use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['user_id'] = df['user_id'].fillna(df.groupby("cookie_id")['user_id'].transform('first'))
print (df)
   user_id  cookie_id
0      2.0         15
1      2.0         15
2      3.0         22
3      2.0         15
4      2.0         15
5      NaN         38
```

Or if need first non missing value per group then use:

```
df['user_id'] = df.groupby("cookie_id")['user_id'].transform('first')
```

Comment: much simpler ... :)